# antlr How to specify regular expressions with the repitition between 2 to infinity

Tags: regex, antlr, antlr4

How to specify regular expressions with the repitition of ANTLR between 2 to infinity

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify with most regexes the notion of 0 to infinity as:

```
   (re)*
```

1 to infinity is usually expressed as:

```
   (re)+
```

but in fact you can write this as equivalently as

```
   (re)((re)*)
```

Using the same idea, 2 to infinity can be written as:

```
   (re)((re)+)
```

Any "N to infinity" can be expressed as:

```
   (re_1)(re_2)...(re_N) ((re)*)
```

where there are N (re) followed by re star.